# external Libs pack to python project

Tags: python, svn

I'm trying to use SVN to manage my python project.
I installed many external Libs (the path is like:`"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"`)on Computer A,then I upload the project to the SVN Server.
and then I use Computer B which just has python(v2.7) been installed.I checkout from the SVN server

:here comes the problem..there is no external Libs in computer B.Is there any solution to solve this problem,I don't want to install the external Libs on Computer B again!

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

The normal Python way to deal with this is to use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/) and [requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/), which lets you have multiple sets of installed packages, is also commonly used.

For example, if you have a project which depends on any version of [`itsdangerous`](http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/) and any version of [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) over 0.9, you could have this requirements file:

```
Werkzeug>=0.9
itsdangerous
```

You would usually store that in a file named `requirements.txt`. You would then install the packages like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`pip` will find all of the packages needed not already installed and install them.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually copy the package source code from site-packages to your project folder, and your project folder normally has a higher prority than site-packages.

Then you just need check-in library to your svn.

Comment: as usual,I creat a directory in `project/libs/`.and I put all the libs to this directory from **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\**.and now how can I import dict4ini which was in the site-packages before.I mean is there any solation that I still can use dict4ini just type `import dict4ini`